# Multiple background using one CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to use multiple images as backgrounds.
For example: index page - car image, about me page - notepad image

I tried to add this code:

```
body {
    background:url(images/big_03.jpg), url(images/big_02.jpg),url(images/big_01.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

But I don't know how to switch them. How can I choose which image to use as the background?

Comment: How does your menu look? Or do you have a container for the content?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use a technique call "CSS Sprites". In short, you combine all of your images to one  big image by using a sprite generator tool at http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/. Next, you change the background positions within the big image to get the background image for the element.

You can learn more from [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-CSS-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)

Comment: The advantage of using sprites is that you can get many images loaded in one HTTP request.  Using a sprite for this situation would do more harm than good since only one of the backgrounds will be used for each particular page.  So a sprite of the backgrounds would essentially increase the image download size (slowing down page load time) for no reason.

Comment: I disagree! She tried to set an image for each element on the page, and even if you use images in multiple pages, it will be beneficial to use Sprite. Look at the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a special class to your body element for each page and specify a different background-image for each case.

HTML:

```
<body class="home">
    ...
</body>

<body class="about">
    ...
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body.home{
    background: url(car.jpg);
}

body.about{
    background: url(notepad.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting each `<body>` tag with a specific ID and then style those ID's separately in the CSS:

```
<body id="home"> </body>
```

CSS

```
#home{
    background-color: red;
    //or image, whatever properties you want
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have three options:

1) Code it into the HTML. To do this, change `<body>` in your page to 
    `<;body style="background-image: url(<url of image>); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">`.

I see this as sub-optimal because it means a lot of typing in different places, potentially causing inconsistencies if you want to change, say, background-repeat to repeat-y and forget to change one or more of your pages.

2) Use a "mini-stylesheet" consisting of just one rule specifying the background on each page. I don't think that this is a very good solution, because along with the problems raised by 1), you also have to deal with another HTTP request, which slows down the page load.

3) Use different ids on each body element (so your `<body>` would become `<body id="home">`, `<body id="about">`, or anything else. I think that this is the best solution because it lets you collect all the code in one place:

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

body#home {
    background-image: url(<home image url);
}

body#about {
    background-image: url(<about image url);
}
```

This code can be stuck in the stylesheet that you link to in all your pages, so you don't end up with any extra HTTP requests. If you want to change one of the property/value pairs for body, you don't have to go through lots of files changing every one, you only have to change one.

Answer (score -1):

If you use static Html u can give class to your body element or outer wrapper. Example :

Homepage

```
<body class="homepage">

</body>
```

About Us Page

```
<body class="about_us">

</body>
```

and set css

```
.homepage {
background-image : url('../path/to/image.jpg');
}

.about_us {
background-image : url('../path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

and so on for each page.

Your current css selection working for global body,

```
body {
background:url(images/big_03.jpg), url(images/big_02.jpg),url(images/big_01.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

This type of css working if u want use multiple BG image on page, not made different BG for each page.